# nodejs 413 request entity too large for base64 image

Tags: node.js, express, base64

I am sending a json data that contains base64 of an image

```
{desc: "hi", img: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABMY" }
```

but I am getting this error

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (/Users/mac/Documents/projects/socialmediaclone/backend/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:156:17)
```

Here is my code.

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.json({ limit: "200mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "200mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.text({ limit: "200mb" }));
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/stories", storyRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoutes);
app.use("/api/comments", commentRoutes);
app.use("/api/likes", likeRoutes);
app.use("/api/relationships", relationshipRoutes);
```

Comment: Sending to the server or from the server?

Answer (score -1):

I just removed

```
app.use(express.json());
```

and it worked, because the default limit is 100k if not specified.